# Datatable's structure optimization: 'null' or equal to some value

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, performance

I've google'd it, and find many answers to a similar question, but can't find really good answer, which fulfills my question.

I'm thinking about query performance on big tables with a big amount of data, and about selection from that tables by some conditions.

I want to know, what is better to use in a query for selection by numeric values (for example, *`select * from myTable where myNumericColumn ...`*). What is better here: *is null*, *is not null*, or *=value*. I mean:

```
select * from myTable where myNumericColumn is null
select * from myTable where myNumericColumn is not null
select * from myTable where myNumericColumn != 0
select * from myTable where myNumericColumn = 0
```

I read that SQL Server indexes NULL values, so it is more efficient to use it. But is it real answer or just opinion of some user?

I need to know about SQL Server and Oracle (in a field of my question).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT! I'm sorry for mistake. I meant the optimization of datatable's structure to reach the best query performance while querying it. Should I use some value instead of NULL value to reach a better speed of execution, or I need to use NULLs, or I just need to index the table in a right way. I know that it is opinion-based, but I need the answer from professionals, who works on database's structure development, optimization and querys' performance**

Comment: Your queries are not the same.  The first rule of writing queries is they should return the desired result set; performance is a secondary consideration.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the question. Apologize for a mistake. I meant datatable's structure optimization, and showed example of querying it.

Comment: You are focused on a micro-optimization.  It is better to focus on solving the problem, and then deal later with performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but when you have millions of data rows, micro-optimization also may affect on speed. That's why I want to optimize as well as it is possible. I know what you mean, but I want to consider all advantages and disadvantages of each way

Comment: @Khazratbek, millions of rows is not a big table with the modern hardware and proper index in place. When you get to billions of rows you should test and compare performance on your system and on your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I wondering what is really the question, because you are trying to compare different queries unless the table are prepare accordingly to the test. For performace there are serveral thing can produce different answers, like number of rows, ratio between each value.

Usually the way you write the query is even irrelevant because query optimizer will rearrange the query to get the best result acording with the data and index on the table.

So the best way is testing and check the `QUERY PLAN`

But you have to compare similar things

Create a Table with same number of `NULL` and not `NULL` and you can compare first two queries.

Then create a Table with same number of `0` and `<>0` and compare perfomance.

Answer (score 1):

I have a table with ~2 million user accounts that I'm using for test data. I've added two columns, COL1 & COL2.

- COL1 is either NULL or has a "1". There are ~75k "1" values.
- COL2 is either "0" or a "1". There are ~75k "1" values.

Here is how I set it up:

```
ALTER TABLE Profile.UserAccount ADD COL1 INT NULL
ALTER TABLE Profile.UserAccount ADD COL2 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)

UPDATE Profile.UserAccount -- Update ~75k rows
SET COL1 = 1, 
    COL2 = 1  
WHERE PasswordIsExpired = 'Y'

CREATE INDEX DELETE_ME1 ON Profile.UserAccount (COL1)
CREATE INDEX DELETE_ME2 ON Profile.UserAccount (COL2)
```

I then put the following queries into SSMS and ran them, outputting the query plan. This gives a "Query Cost relative to the batch" as a percent. If they all came back as 25%, that means they would all have an equal cost (4 queries x 25% = 100% of the batch).

I added the query cost next to each statement. The lower the cost, the more efficient the query in respect to the other queries:

```
-- Query Cost: 50%
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Profile.UserAccount WHERE COL1 IS NULL
/*
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 12 ms, elapsed time = 12 ms.
Table 'UserAccount'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2634, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 250 ms,  elapsed time = 481 ms.
*/

-- Query Cost: 3%
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Profile.UserAccount WHERE COL1 IS NOT NULL
/*
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'UserAccount'. Scan count 1, logical reads 136, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 35 ms.
 */

-- Query Cost: 45%
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Profile.UserAccount WHERE COL2 = 0
/*
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'UserAccount'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2068, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 250 ms,  elapsed time = 441 ms.
*/

-- Query Cost: 2%
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Profile.UserAccount WHERE COL2 != 0
/*
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'UserAccount'. Scan count 2, logical reads 113, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 159 ms.
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is SQL Server, right?

Comment: Oh, sorry. *SSMS* - it is exactly SQL Server :) Sorry, I just didn't noticed that

Comment: Since you have the test case ready, could you measure the actual performance as well, in addition to looking at the estimated query cost? Add `SET STATISTICS IO ON; SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` before your `COUNT(*)` queries. Then check the Messages tab.

Comment: But you **cant** compare `WHERE COL2 = 0` and `WHERE COL2 != 0`, because there are 2 million `0` and  75k `1` is obvious first one will take longer. Same for `NULL` test, first one has more rows to count and cost will be higher. The index will reduce the cost of the second one because index will filter more rows from start.

Comment: As @JuanCarlosOropeza explains, this example mostly shows that counting more rows that match a filter takes more time.